# Getting error in vba subscript out of range for array and for loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have the follow code to fill cells in excel one by one and it works the way I want it to but it gives me this error when it runs through the array. How do I fix this error? Thanks

The error is "Subscript out of range. Error: 9"

```
Dim item As Variant
Dim splitString() As String
Dim finalSplit() As String
i = 1
For Each item In splitString
    finalSplit = Split(splitString(s), ",")
    Cells(i, 1) = finalSplit(0)
    Cells(i, 2) = finalSplit(1)
    Cells(i, 3) = finalSplit(2)
    Cells(i, 4) = finalSplit(3)
    i = i + 1
    s = s + 1
Next
```

I checked if finalSplit contains enough values like Thomas said and it worked.This is the new code below.

```
 Dim item As Variant
    Dim splitString() As String
    Dim finalSplit() As String
    i = 1
    For Each item In splitString
        finalSplit = Split(splitString(s), ",")
If UBound(finalSplit) > 1 Then
        Cells(i, 1) = finalSplit(0)
        Cells(i, 2) = finalSplit(1)
        Cells(i, 3) = finalSplit(2)
        Cells(i, 4) = finalSplit(3)
        i = i + 1
        s = s + 1
End If
    Next
```

Comment: One of your arrays has fewer elements than the index you are passing. You can use `Ubound` to limit it to only legitimate indexes.

Comment: You need to check if `finalSplit` contains enough values, eg `If Ubound(finalSplit) > 1 Then Cells(i, 2) = finalSplit(1)`

Comment: Since you're already doing `For Each item In splitString` you might as well utilize the `item` variable: `finalSplit = Split(item, ",")` making `s` redundant.

Answer (score 0):

As other commenters have pointed out, why not add another control variable?

```
Dim item As Variant
Dim splitString() As String
Dim finalSplit() As String
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, s As Integer
i = 1
For Each item In splitString
    finalSplit = Split(splitString(s), ",")
    For j = 0 To UBound(finalSplit)
        Cells(i, j + 1) = finalSplit(j)
    Next j
    i = i + 1
    s = s + 1
Next
```

Be aware that this can loop more than the 4 times you expect. A lazy way to solve this would be to add `If j > 3 Then Exit For` before `Next j`

I tested this with the following code (it works!), as I have no idea what splitString() or finalSplit() is in your case:

```
Sub test()
    Dim finalSplit As Variant
    Dim j As Integer
    finalSplit = Split("1,2,3,4,5", ",")
    For j = 0 To UBound(finalSplit)
        Cells(1, j + 1) = finalSplit(j)
        If j > 3 Then Exit For
    Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: Another option might be to take the minimum of `4` and `UBound(finalSplit)` and loop to that, but `Exit For` is perfectly valid too.

Answer (score 0):

### Looping Through Elements of Arrays

- An array created by the `Split` function is always 0-based (even if `Option Base 1`). Similarly, not quite related, an array created by the `Array` function is dependent on `Option Base` unless you use its parent `VBA` e.g. `arr = VBA.Array(1,2,3)`. Then it is always zero-based.
- Looping through the elements of an array (1D array) is done in the following two ways:

  - `For Each...Next`

    ```
    Dim Item As Variant
    For Each Item In Arr 
        Debug.Print Item
    Next Item
    ```
  - `For...Next`

    ```
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(Arr) To Ubound(Arr)
        Debug.Print Arr(i)
    Next i
    ```
- Since we have established that `Split` always produces a zero-based array, in the second example we could use `0` instead of `LBound(Arr)`:

  ```
  `For...Next`
  Dim i As Long
  For i = 0 To Ubound(Arr)
      Debug.Print Arr(i)
  Next i
  ```

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DoubleSplit()
    
    Const IniString As String = "A,B,C,D/E,F,G,H/I,J,K/L/M,N,O,P,Q,R"
    
    Dim SplitString() As String: SplitString = Split(IniString, "/")
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' be more specific
    ws.Cells.ClearContents ' remove previous data; clears the whole worksheet
    
    Dim FinalSplit() As String
    Dim Item As Variant ' SplitString Control Variable
    Dim r As Long ' Worksheet Row Counter
    Dim f As Long ' FinalSplit Element Counter
    
    ' For Each...Next
    For Each Item In SplitString
        r = r + 1
        FinalSplit = Split(Item, ",")
        Debug.Print Join(FinalSplit, ",")
        For f = 0 To UBound(FinalSplit)
            ws.Cells(r, f + 1).Value = FinalSplit(f)
        Next f
    Next Item

    r = r + 1 ' add an empty row
    
    Dim s As Long ' SplitString Element Counter

    ' For...Next
    For s = 0 To UBound(SplitString)
        r = r + 1
        FinalSplit = Split(SplitString(s), ",")
        Debug.Print Join(FinalSplit, ",")
        For f = 0 To UBound(FinalSplit)
            ws.Cells(r, f + 1).Value = FinalSplit(f)
        Next f
    Next s

' Results

' A,B,C,D
' E,F,G,H
' I,J,K
' L
' M,N,O,P,Q,R
'
' A,B,C,D
' E,F,G,H
' I,J,K
' L
' M,N,O,P,Q,R

End Sub
```